# Django - how to exclude results from existing querysets in following model queries?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models: `Peers` and `Competitors`, which are related to a `Client` model.  All have a basic ID field.

Lets say I execute a `*.objects.filter(id = some_id)` query on `Peers` and `Competitors`

Rather than writing my own loops, is there a built in way for Django to allow me to get all `Client` objects that do not exist in the `Peer` and `Competitor` querysets?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
clients = Client.objects.exclude(peer__client=client_id) 
clients = clients.exclude(competitor__client=client_id)
```

I assume your Foreign key is named `client` in both `Peer` and `Competitor` models.